# python vs pythonw

Tags: python, python-2.7, pythonw

The man page describes `pythonw2.7` as follows:

> NAME
>
> pythonw -- run python script allowing GUI

However, the man page also states this:

> Actually, since Python 2.5, the normal python also allows GUI access,
>   so python and pythonw are now interchangeable.

What differences, if any, exist between python and pythonw now? I can't seem to find any much info about it.

Comment: It doesn't say they're the same, it says they're interchangeable.

Comment: @Coldspeed pythonw doesn't give a console window and thus is used for GUI. The performance measurement you performed is insignificant, 525 is too  close to 552. python.exe in Windows starts a new console window, there has to be technically some extra stuff, but that's again not significantly slower.

Comment: I am not getting any consistent timing results that prove that one is faster than other on MacOS. In fact their binary are same sized and their diff results nothing.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Then what I got was just luck of the draw? Hmm, that could possibly make sense, given that they _are_ supposed to be identical.